# Kafka deserialisation error and logging the partition, topic and offset

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

I am handling deserialisation errors using the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` sent on my `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory`.

```java
try (ErrorHandlingDeserializer<MyEvent> errorHandlingDeserializer = new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(theRealDeserialiser)) {
    errorHandlingDeserializer.setFailedDeserializationFunction(myCustomFunction::apply);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(getConsumerProperties(), consumerKeyDeserializer, errorHandlingDeserializer);
}
```

My custom function does some processing and publishes to a poison pill topic and returns `null`.

When a deserialisation error occurs, I would like to log the topic, partition and offset. The only way I can think of doing this is to stop returning null in the function and return a new sub type of `MyEvent`. My `KafkaListener` could then interrogate the new sub type.

I have a `@KafkaListener` component, which listens for the `ConsumerRecord` as follows:

```
@KafkaListner(....)
public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, MyEvent> record) {
  ...
  ...
  
// if record.value instance of MyNewSubType
//   I have access to the topic, partition and offset here, so I could log it here
// I'd have to check that the instance of MyEvent is actually my sub type representing a failed record.

}
```

Is this the way to do it? I know `null` has special meaning Kafka.

The downside of this subtype approach is, I'd have to create a subtype every type using the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a function; instead, the thrown `DeserializationException` is passed directly the container's `ErrorHandler`.

The `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` considers these exceptions to be fatal and won't retry them, it passes the record to the recoverer.

There is a provided `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` which sends the record.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#dead-letters

Comment: I am also setting STCEH along with DeadLetterPublishingRecover on my ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory, but that is for handing non-poison errors. I want the poison errors to go to topic X and non poison to topic Y. That is why I have made the function publish to a poison pill topic.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, I don't need to set a function.
Instead, I can set a STCEH, and in the recover I should interrogate the exception.
If it's a DeserializationException, I can publish to poison, alternatively my second topic.

Comment: Yes - use a custom `destinationResolver` - it is called with the consumer record and exception to determine which topic and partition to publish to. See the documentation I referred you to.

Comment: Ok, so I created a subclass of DeadLetterPublisherRecover and provided a custom destination Resolver BiFunction. I'm checking if it's an instance of DeseriaizationException, I return a TopicPartition containing the name of my poison topic. Otherwise the other topic. 

Problem is I'm getting a ListenerExectionFailedException instead (which has a cause of DeserializationException). Should I be inspecting the cause?

Comment: Yes; all exceptions are wrapped in a LEFE - strictly speaking it's not a failure in the listener, but we always wrap for consistency. You shouldn't need to subclass the DLPR, you can just pass a custom destination resolving function into the constructor (unless you need to subclass it for some other reason).

Comment: If I use the STCEH, do I need to be concerned with committing offset when error occurs? Or will I get this out of the box?

Comment: By default, a successfully "recovered" (record sent to the DLT) will have its offset committed by the container when the error handler exits.

Comment: Great. Thanks Gary.